# interface for only certain classes?

Tags: java, language-features, language-design

Can you create an interface which can only be applied to certain classes and subclasses?

If my interface is **only** added to *different* subclasses of JComponent, and I need to refer to both the methods of JComponent and my interface...  how should I do this?  Off the top of my head I can accomplish this by adding methods from JComponent to my interface.

This seems clumsy.  What is a better way to do this?

Comment: Is the problem is that your interface has the same method names as JComponent, and there will be a conflict?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious solution is to add a method to your interface that returns the component (which may be `this`).

```
JComponent getComponent();
```

Or even genericise your interface:

```
 public interface MyInterface<C extends JComponent> {
     C getComponent();
     [...]
 }
```

It's not great design, but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

There might be scenarios where this won't work, but using generics lets you specify several types:

```
interface Foo { void frobulize(); }

class Bar {
    <T extends JComponent & Foo> String doFoo(T obj){
        obj.frobulize();
        return obj.getToolTipText();
    }
}
```

If you want the objects as fields on a non-parametrized type, you add type parameters to the constructor (a little-known feature which is bound to confuse and impress your colleagues):

```
class Quux {
    private final Foo foo;
    private final JComponent component;
    public <T extends JComponent & Foo> Quux(T fc){
        foo = fc;
        component = fc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, would it even be possible to overwrite `foo` and `component` as they are final?

Comment: Absolutely, assuming the fields are non-final (unlike my example) you can make a setter like `public <T extends JComponent & Foo> void setFooComponent(T fc){ foo = fc; component = fc; } `